# New activity is only displaying the last element of the arraylist when clicked from recycler view - don't know what is wrong

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android Studio, and have encountered a problem. I'm currently creating a feature where there will be a recycler view containing FAQs, upon clicking the FAQ row, the user will be taken to a new activity where there will be more information.

How I'm attempting to do that is through an arraylist in a class, where i store the information that will be passed to the rows, and subsequently the last activity. However, for some reason, when I finished writing my code, only the last element in the arraylist is displayed in the last activity (ie. I will have 5 different elements that show up in the recyclerview, but whichever row i click on, only the last element's information will be displayed)

Please give me some ideas, because this method of code has worked before and I have no idea why it's not working now.

This is the class that i'm entering the data in

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InfoPageClass {


    public InfoPageClass(String infoCode, String infoName, String infoCategory, String infoContent){
        this.infoCode = infoCode;
        this.infoName = infoName;
        this.infoCategory = infoCategory;
        this.infoContent = infoContent;
    }

    private String infoCode;
    private String infoName;
    private String infoCategory;
    private String infoContent;


    public  String getInfoName() {
        return infoName;
    }

    public void setInfoName(String infoName) {
        this.infoName = infoName;
    }

    public  String getInfoCategory() {
        return infoCategory;
    }

    public void setInfoCategory(String infoCategory) {
        this.infoCategory = infoCategory;
    }

    public String getInfoContent() {
        return infoContent;
    }

    public void setInfoContent(String infoContent) {
        this.infoContent = infoContent;
    }

    public String getInfoCode() {
        return infoCode;
    }

    public void setInfoCode(String infoCode) {
        this.infoCode = infoCode;
    }

    public static ArrayList<InfoPageClass> getInfoPage(){
        ArrayList<InfoPageClass> infoPage = new ArrayList<>();
//        infoPage.add(new InfoPageClass("111", "How do I use this app?", "General", "This app was created with the objective to promote healthy-eating and improve the general " + "quality of life by educating individuals on what they include in their diet. \n" +
//                "This is achieved via key lessons teaching the basics of healthy eating, as well as a database that details the nutritional value" +
//                "of the foods available to individuals. Finally, through gamification, the app aims to cement this knowledge by testing individuals through an interactive quiz format"));
        infoPage.add(new InfoPageClass("222", "blah1","blah1", "blah1"));
        infoPage.add(new InfoPageClass("333", "blah2","blah2", "sfdsdfwesfwefwdfsdfsdf"));

        return infoPage;
    }

    public static InfoPageClass getInfoPage(String infoCode){
        ArrayList<InfoPageClass> infoPage = InfoPageClass.getInfoPage();
        for (final InfoPageClass infoName : infoPage){
            if(infoName.getInfoCode().equals(infoCode)){
                return infoName;
            }
        }

        return infoPage.get(infoPage.size()-1);
    }

}
```

This is my recyclerview code

```
public class InfoPageList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView3;
    private InfoPageAdapter mAdapter3;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_page_list);

        mRecyclerView3 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView3);
        mRecyclerView3.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView3.setLayoutManager(layoutManager3);
        InfoPageAdapter.Listener listener = new InfoPageAdapter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, String infoCode) {
                launchDetailActivity(infoCode);
            }
        };

        mAdapter3 = new InfoPageAdapter(InfoPageClass.getInfoPage(), listener);
        mRecyclerView3.setAdapter(mAdapter3);
    }

//create method to change to infopagedetailed activity where more faq questions are answered
    private void launchDetailActivity(String message){
        Intent intent = new Intent(InfoPageList.this, InfoPageDetailed.class);
        intent.putExtra(InfoPageDetailed.INTENT_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the code to set the text of the last activity (where it's displaying the wrong information)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfoPageDetailed extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String INTENT_MESSAGE = "au.edu.unsw.infs3634.gamifiedlearning.intent_message";
    TextView mInfoName;
    TextView mInfoContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_page_detailed);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String infoCode = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_MESSAGE);
        final InfoPageClass infoPageClass = InfoPageClass.getInfoPage(infoCode);


        mInfoName = findViewById(R.id.tvInfoTitle2);
        mInfoContent = findViewById(R.id.tvInfoContent);

//Set the values 
        mInfoName.setText(infoPageClass.getInfoName());
        mInfoContent.setText(infoPageClass.getInfoContent());

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I'm thinking it may be an issue with the for loop in the infopageclass, but again, i'm not sure what may be wrong since this method has worked previously

Comment: Can you explain what data you wanna display in each activity opened? What is the data being displayed by "last element"?

Comment: Hi, in the last activity, i'm lookg to display the infoContent and the infoName from the arraylist class, while in the recyclerview i'm trying to display the infoName and infoCategory from the arraylist @PrinceAli

Comment: I was asking for actual data, not the coding data. If you have an FAQ, why not create several cardviews and then open an activity on click listener and display the data that you want in that activity without using all these codes?

Comment: Hi, you make a very good point, and I've changed the app accordingly. However, I still face a similar issue with a different function of the app - where the detailed activity page only displays the last element in the arraylist - so I still need to rectify this issue unfortunately

Comment: What is that element? What are you expecting to be displayed in the activity? How do you get the data? Similar codes as in question?